# error: parser: instruction expected while asembling my code

Tags: ubuntu, unix, assembly

i am using ubuntu 20.04 and i am new at asmebly languge. plz guide me regarding this error.
i want read a char from keyboard and print it on console.

1. here is code

.MODEl SMALL
.STACK 100h
.CODE

MAIN PROC
mov       ah,01
int       21h
mov       bl,al
mov       ah,02
mov       dl,bl
int       21h

END MAIN

**output**
[image]

Comment: That's not a source format accepted by NASM.

Comment: then what format it can be. please guide.

Comment: That code is MASM/TASM and specifically for writing DOS applications.

Comment: You should probably find a tutorial for NASM specifically. [Tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/index.htm) has on OK tutorial that I first used, but its for 32-bit assembly and only went into the very basics. [This](https://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/nasmtutorial/) is also a good tutorial for x64, but you might just find it to be a bit too fast-paced. And, of course, always keep the [NASM manual](https://www.nasm.us/doc/) handy.

Comment: Oh, and also something to note: That NASM manual may have a few features you won't be able to use because last time I checked, NASM 2.15.05 is not supported for debian-based systems. I believe the version you probably have is 2.14.02, so here's the manual for that: https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.14.02/nasmdoc.pdf